# Rails select2 after create new tag i haven't id on create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-select2

I use `select2` and want to create new tags and then save them.

i have form for `@cost` and for `select2` this

```
<%= f.collection_select :product_ids, Product.all,:id, :name ,{include_hidden: false},{ multiple: true} %>
```

for creation new product i have this `js code`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#cost_product_ids').select2({
    tags: true,
    tokenSeparators: [",", " "],
    createProduct: function (product) {
        return {
            id: product.term,
            text: product.term,
            isNew: true
        };
    }
}).on("change", function (e) {
    var isNew = $(this).find('[data-select2-tag="true"]');
    if (isNew.length) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/product_new",
            data: {product: isNew.val()}
        });

    }
});
```

});

and controller method for save new product

```
  def product_new
   product = Product.find_by(name:params[:product])
   Product.create(name:params[:product]) if !product
   render json: :ok
  end
```

`cost create` action

```
   def create
    @cost = Cost.new(costs_params)
    if @cost.save
      flash[:notice] = t('added')
      if params[:add_more].present?
        redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)
      else
        redirect_to @cost
      end
    else
      render action: 'edit'
    end
  end

   def costs_params
    params.require(:cost).permit(:day, :amount, :description, :source,:tag_list,:product_ids=>[])
  end
```

it works ok, but when i want to save my @cost record with this newly created product i have received only name of my tag without id.

For example i have products `water=>id:1,beer=>id:2,and create new juice tag` in db it has `id:3`

on create in have params `"product_ids"=>["1", "2", "juice"]`

How to fix it?

Comment: Can you add some informations about the cost record, maybe the cost controller or action where it is to be saved?

Comment: updated @CdotStrifeVII

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't use        id: product.term,
but   `id: product.id,`